# Why does my flask app gives a method not allowed error?

Tags: python, html, multithreading, flask

I'm trying threading on my flask app so that it doesn't time out with the process which takes a lot of time. I try to run this but it gives me a "GET /process_files HTTP/1.1" 405 -" problem and never finishes the task. Why does it trying a GET request on process_files?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, send_file
import pandas as pd
from Cometa import cometa_process
import threading

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['TIMEOUT'] = 1200

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def process_and_save_csv(stock_file, sales_file):
    # Read CSV files
    stock = pd.read_csv(stock_file)
    sales = pd.read_csv(sales_file)

    # Process CSV files
    result_df = cometa_process(stock, sales)

    # Save processed CSV file to disk
    with open('result.csv', 'w') as f:
        result_df.to_csv(f, index=False)

@app.route('/process_files', methods=['POST'])
def process_files():
    stock_file = request.files['stock']
    sales_file = request.files['sales']

    # Start a new thread to process and save the CSV files
    thread = threading.Thread(target=process_and_save_csv, args=(stock_file, sales_file))
    thread.start()

    return 'Files are being processed. Check back in a few minutes to download the result.'

@app.route('/download_file')
def download_file():
    return send_file('result.csv', as_attachment=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

And this is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload CSV files</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ url_for('process_files') }}">
        <input type="file" name="stock"><br>
        <input type="file" name="sales"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply in the route where the form is used which is in `index.html`
Your code must be like this:
**Python file**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, send_file
import pandas as pd
from Cometa import cometa_process
import threading

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['TIMEOUT'] = 1200

@app.route('/',methods=['POST','GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html')
    else:
        stock_file = request.files['stock']
        sales_file = request.files['sales']
    
        # Start a new thread to process and save the CSV files
        thread = threading.Thread(target=process_and_save_csv, args=(stock_file, sales_file))
        thread.start()
        return redirect(url_for('process_files'))

def process_and_save_csv(stock_file, sales_file):
    # Read CSV files
    stock = pd.read_csv(stock_file)
    sales = pd.read_csv(sales_file)

    # Process CSV files
    result_df = cometa_process(stock, sales)

    # Save processed CSV file to disk
    with open('result.csv', 'w') as f:
        result_df.to_csv(f, index=False)


@app.route('/download_file')
def download_file():
    return send_file('result.csv', as_attachment=True)


@app.route('/process_files')
def process_files():
    return 'Files are being processed. Check back in a few minutes to download the result.'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload CSV files</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/">
        <input type="file" name="stock"><br>
        <input type="file" name="sales"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```